# Errors when I return false inside html tags. Eclipse does not like returns outside functions or methods

Tags: eclipse, events, event-handling, dom-events, eclipse-pdt

Eclipse PDT is outputting errors every time it encounters a Return statement outside a function or method. See below the exact error message:

> Cannot return from outside a function or method.

As an example I am including a code snippet below:

```
<form onsubmit="insertAbbr();return false;" action="#">
```

Eclipse doesn't like the `return false;` inside the tag.

After a lot of research I found a number of suggestions on how to fix it:

Attempt 1: call a Javascript function to return false

```
<form onsubmit="insertAbbr();javascript: function () {return false;};" action="#">
```

Same error.

Attempt 2: change the way I call the Javascript function

```
<form onsubmit="insertAbbr();javascript: return false;" action="#">
```

Same error.

And to add to the confusion, when I do check on all major browsers, the original syntax with return false; works without any errors.

Can anyone help me figure out how to resolve this issue? If I can help it, I would like to avoid turning off the validation or hiding the error in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this appears to be a known bug in Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353209

I haven't been able to find a workaround, but at least this confirms that it's not something you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you. After a while I gave up trying to find a solution.